# Does pygal support Legend title?

Tags: python, pygal

Does pygal support legend title? In matplotlib, you can specify a separate title for the legends in graph. Does pygal offer something equivalent?

Comment: pygal documentation does not mention this feature. I was wondering if anyone have any workaround?